# There are two men in the hairdressing salon. / There are two men at the hairdresser's

Tags: sentence-construction

> There are two men **in the hairdressing salon**.
>
> There are two men **at the hairdresser's**.

For me, the first sentence is quite clear, but is the second sentence also correct? Is it OK to use "there are" with the end of the sentence "at the hairdresser's"?

Maybe, I can only say: "Two men are **at the hairdresser's**."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use "there are" with the end of the sentence "at the hairdresser's"

It is fine to use a prepositional phrase as a complement in a "there are" type sentence.

> There is an apple on the table.

Comment: Hairdresser or Hairdresser's   Not sure which form sounds better.